# Setting _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, window-managers

With other toolkits there's usually a way to set `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG` so that my tiling window manager (i3) renders it properly without needing an explicit rule for the window. It seems like I should be able to do this with either `Tk.attributes()` or `Tk.wm_attributes()`, but every keyword argument I've tried (`type` and `toolwindow`) are unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

Took a much closer look at the doc.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-type', 'dialog')

a = tk.Frame(master=root)
root.title(__file__)
a.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you certain the code works? I couldn't make it work, it lacks `mainloop` for one.

Comment: @Nae oh yeah obviously it won't, it doesn't even have an import. was just meant as a snippet. i've edited it for completeness.